# Animation freeze screen's other objects and scrolling. How to handle mutiple continues animation in same controller

Tags: ios, swift, animation, image-rotation

I'm performing a rotation animation in home screen and also added card view and collection in same screen.
Now, All working fine but screen and animation freeze when i move card or scroll collection. It cause problem animation while doing a repeat rotation animation only.

Here is my code which i used for rotation animation.
Also, tried with dispatch queue but it doesn't worked for me.

```
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 5.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat , .autoreverse], animations: { self.Img_Rotate.transform=self.Img_Rotate.transform.rotated(by: .pi - 0.00001)}) { (complete) in }
```

Is there any best way to handle multiple animations in the same screen or app.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Try to add this in option ```.allowUserInteraction```

Comment: I did but it's not worked for me.